# How to create new DataFrame with all non-NaN values from other DataFrames in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two `DataFrames`; `df1` and `df2` and they both contain mostly `NaN` values. They have non-NaN values at the same locations in the data set. Based on these two `DataFrames`, I would like to create `df` with a column for all values from `df1` and one column for `df2`, so that I have value pairs from both `DataFrames`.

Here I created a simple example:

```
df1:
            01K 02K 03K 04K
Dates               
2021-01-01  NaN NaN NaN NaN
2021-01-02  NaN 2.5 NaN NaN
2021-01-03  NaN NaN 4.1 NaN
2021-01-04  8.2 NaN 9.0 NaN
2021-01-05  NaN 1.2 NaN NaN
2021-01-06  NaN NaN NaN NaN

df2:
            01K 02K 03K 04K
Dates               
2021-01-01  NaN NaN NaN NaN
2021-01-02  NaN 0.6 NaN NaN
2021-01-03  NaN NaN 0.4 NaN
2021-01-04  0.1 NaN 0.2 NaN
2021-01-05  NaN 0.2 NaN NaN
2021-01-06  NaN NaN NaN NaN

df:
    df1 df2
0   8.2 0.1
1   2.5 0.6
2   1.2 0.2
3   4.1 0.4
4   9.0 0.2
```

For reproducibility:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dates':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06'],
    '01K':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 8.2, np.nan, np.nan], 
    '02K':[np.nan, 2.5, np.nan, np.nan, 1.2, np.nan], 
    '03K':[np.nan, np.nan, 4.1, 9.0, np.nan, np.nan], 
    '04K':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}) 
df1 = df1.set_index('Dates')

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dates':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06'],
    '01K':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.1, np.nan, np.nan], 
    '02K':[np.nan, 0.6, np.nan, np.nan, 0.2, np.nan], 
    '03K':[np.nan, np.nan, 0.4, 0.2, np.nan, np.nan], 
    '04K':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}) 
df2 = df2.set_index('Dates')
```

Thanks a lot for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stack` to get rid of the nan's:

```
pd.DataFrame({'df1': df1.stack(), 'df2': df2.stack()})
```

output:

```
                df1  df2
Dates                   
2021-01-02 02K  2.5  0.6
2021-01-03 03K  4.1  0.4
2021-01-04 01K  8.2  0.1
           03K  9.0  0.2
2021-01-05 02K  1.2  0.2
```

Comment: Many thanks, that works fine! How would you change the code to get it unconditional of the dates and column names?

Comment: @fjurt chain that with `reset_index(drop=True)`.